# Div not 100% width of browser

Tags: css, html

My div will not stretch the full width of the browser, it stops short on both ends by about 10px.

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #088ed7;
  width: auto;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">...</div>
```

I've tried both `auto` and `100%` but still get the same outcome.

Comment: Please provide a link to the page or preferably to a jsfiddle so we can see your page code. The code above has nothing to stop this occurring so the problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: Do you have padding or margin on your .header div? Or, padding or margin on its container div?

Comment: There is probably padding on the containing div or body tag.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's likely the page's margin and/or padding.

Add:

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #088ed7;
  width: auto;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">...</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To many off my project, I'm adding the following reset css. Then, no more issues =)

**CSS**

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
a img {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following css rule:

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css in your code, the new unit "vw" viewport width is used to set the width of the element to the view port.

```
 html,body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
 }
 .header{
    width:100vw;
 }
```

For more details please refer the link: 
https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Comment: Pls edit answer in meaningful manner. Add description for this

Comment: edited please share your comments to improve the answer

Comment: I changed your answer. Pls check

Answer (score 0):

put this in CSS file it worked for me
I found that the minimum width of a container is set to `576px` when I open the developer tools so use this in your CSS file and it will solve your problem:

```
@media (min-width: 576px){
   .container, .container-sm {
      max-width: 100%;
   }
}
```