# HTML/CSS: <div> has not hundred percent width

Tags: html, css

I want a div, which acts as a separator. It should have a hundred percent width. However, it doesn't align with the border of the browser.

What is wrong? I tested it with the latest firefox and chrome:

```html
<div style="background-color: black;height:4px;display:block;"></div>
    
    <div><p>Content</p></div>
    
    <div style="height:20px;"></div>
```

I also tested the CSS-style "border" instead of background-color, but it has the same result.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+html+css+div+does+not+have+100%25+width) of [Div not 100% width of browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19184691/4642212).

Comment: cannot replicate the issue. probably something is interfering with this sample

Comment: @LelioFaieta _“However, it doesn't align with the border of the browser.”_ — Does your browser have a body margin of 0 by default?

Comment: @SebastianSimon the div has a 100% width. The border of the browser can be 0 or the browser can add a margin to the body but he is asking for the width to be 100% and to fit the "border" without specifying which one. Also, since the body margin will cover the full page the div will be aligned with the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the margin from the body:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: black; height: 4px; display: block;"></div>
<div><p>Content</p></div>
<div style="height: 20px;"></div>
```

Inline version:

```
<body style="margin: 0;">
```

Comment: Thank you, it never occurred to me that the browser has a default margin

Answer (score -2):

give 100% width to body. it will fix the problem.